# Hamburger menu is not visible on safari mobile

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cross-browser

I have a problem with my site displaying on Safari on iPhone.

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox on mobile screens. 
On Safari the div with menu hamburger disappears.

Look at the screenshots below:

The site on Chrome/Firefox:

[image]

The site on Safari:

[image]

Do you have any idea why it breaks on Safari? I would be very grateful for any tips.

Here is the link to the site: https://sylwiavv.github.io/blood-donation-landing-page-starter-master

Here is the link to the source code: https://github.com/sylwiavv/blood-donation-landing-page-starter-master

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code here to repro the issue. Having a link to code will be frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the `overflow-y: hidden` in [`style.css`](https://sylwiavv.github.io/blood-donation-landing-page-starter-master/css/styles.css) ([Repo](https://github.com/sylwiavv/blood-donation-landing-page-starter-master/blob/master/css/styles.css#L177)) line 169.

```css
  .overlay{
    height:100%;
    width:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#f995c2;
    /* overflow-y:hidden;          /* Remove this line */
    transition:0.6s;
  }
```

Removing it works! Even setting the rule with appropriate `width` and `height` like this way works:

```css
.overlay{
  height:75px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#f995c2;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  transition:0.6s;
}
```

Comment: Praveen Kumar Purushothaman thank you for your answer!  When I remove overflow-y:hidden the content of menu becomes visible I want the menu content to be visible only when I click on menu button. The similar effect happens when I set width and height.

Comment: @SylwiaW Oh... 